# Need 30 line pdf from Tex

Tags: pdfpages

My latex file produce 48 line PDF while I need 30 line PDF in result. What should be added\inserted to get the desired result?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you intend to enlarge the page margins, decrease the font size or what else?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! At the moment this question is quite unclear to me, it almost sounds as if you've just written too much?? I wonder if you mean to ask how you can make your content take up less space on the page, in which case, the sorts of things @CarLaTeX suggests would be a good place to start, but it'd be much easier to help you if we could see some code and some output.

Comment: Scientific Work Place (SWP) produce a pdf of normaly 30 Lines (rows) on each phage. But the pdf produced by my TAX file have 48 lines(rows) with less space between two lines (rows). I need phage of 30 lines(rows) with no change in font size???

Comment: As @Au101 suggested, could you edit your post adding a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: Thanks I get my desired PDF just by adding \usepackage{setspace}       \doublespacing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question allows many interpretations:

1. Whole text ≤ 30 lines:

   - Adding `\end{document}` at the end of the 30th line, cutting off line 31 to 48.
   - Shorten the text to 30 lines.
2. Page layout with 30 lines:

   a) Change of font size.

   b) Change of page margins.

   c) Landscape instead of portrait.

   d) About 1½ linespacing:

   ```
   \usepackage{setspace}
   \onehalfspacing
   ```

The methods can also be combined. I have omitted the precise values, because they depend on many other things like the used fonts, the page size, ...
My guess for the requirement would be something like 2.d).

Comment: Thanks                                                              I get my desired PDF just by adding                            \usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing